# Is there any alternative way to get azure clientID other then registering active directory?

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

```
var authenticationContext = new AuthenticationContext(activeDirectoryEndpoint + activeDirectoryTenantId);
var credential = new ClientCredential(clientId: clientId, clientSecret: clientSecret);
var result = authenticationContext.AcquireTokenAsync(resource: windowsManagementUri, clientCredential: credential).Result;
```

I have this chunk of code which does generate token, is there any other way to get clientID and Client Secret , without using azure active directory app registration?

Comment: Client id is the ID of the application registered in Azure AD. I am curious to know your use case for want to get the client id/secret without using app registration.

Comment: I was exploring , is there any alternative to authenticate an app other than AD. Looks like there is no alternative.

Answer (score 0):

The way you acquire the token following the **OAuth 2.0 Authorization Framework** which enables a third-party
application to obtain limited access to an HTTP service, either on
behalf of a resource owner by orchestrating an approval interaction
between the resource owner and the HTTP service, or by allowing the
third-party application to obtain access on its own behalf. .

We can integrate with any platform which support OAuth 2.0. For example, if you want to integrate with Azure AD, you need to register the app on Azure then use this app's property to integrate with Azure AD to acquire the token. Same as Google, Fackbook etc.

More detail about OAuth 2.0 Authorization Framework, you can refer [here](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749).

Comment: Thanks for commenting, but i was exploring was there any alternative to AD. but there is no.

Comment: If you were developing with web app via Visual Studio, it will register the app for us when you choose [Organizational Account](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/visual-studio/overview/2013/creating-web-projects-in-visual-studio#organizational-account-authentication-options)

Answer (score 0):

If you're willing to use Powershell, you can use the [Azure AD v2.0 cmdlets](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/azuread/v2/azureactivedirectory). This allows you to create an app in your tenant, and will return the AppID.

The specific cmdlet you'll want to checkout:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/azuread/v2/new-azureadapplication

Comment: Thanks for commenting, but i was exploring was there any alternative to AD. but there is no.